# How can I remove the last item in the BackStack in a non-Silverlight app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

Suppose I have 2 pages: `Page1` and `Page2`.

When my app starts, I navigate to `Page1` which eventually navigates to `Page2`.  On `Page2`, I want to prevent the user from using the back button to return to `Page1`.  Similarly, I want to prevent the user from navigating from `Page1` to `Page2` using the back button (navigation to `Page1` from `Page2` is possible).

I know in Silverlight apps, you'd simply use:

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

However, my app is built using Windows 10 APIs, which aren't Silverlight-based.  I've tried doing:
In `Page2`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    //...
    if (e.SourcePageType == typeof(Page1)) 
        Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(Frame.BackStackDepth - 1); // remove the last entry if it represents Page1.
    //...
}
```

And in `Page1`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    //...
    if (e.SourcePageType == typeof(Page2)) 
        Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(Frame.BackStackDepth - 1); // remove the last entry if it represents Page2.
    //...
}
```

I also tried using `Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(0);` and `Frame.BackStack.Remove(new PageStackEntry(e.SourcePageType, e.Parameter, e.NavigationTransitionInfo);` instead of `Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(Frame.BackStackDepth - 1);`.

None of this does what I want it to.  What can I do to make this work?

Comment: I just tried `Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(Frame.BackStackDepth - 1)` and it works flawlessly. What's your issue? How do you handle the back button press?

Comment: @KooKiz I've been using `e.SourcePageType` to check if the previous page, and that seems to just be the current page.  Not the actual source.  I'm going to add a way for me to determine the actual source page.  I'll update here afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.SourcePageType` seems to return the type of the **current page** rather than the actual source.  I solved this problem by adding the following code:
For `Page1` (since `Page1` sometimes receives a `Frame.Navigate()` call from `App.xaml.cs`, an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` would occur because there is no back stack at that time, so a try-catch was needed):

```
try {
    if (Frame.BackStack[Frame.BackStackDepth - 1].SourcePageType == typeof(Page2))
        Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(Frame.BackStackDepth - 1);
}
catch (Exception) { // an ArgumentOutOfRangeException }
```

Then in `Page2`:

```
if (Frame.BackStack[Frame.BackStackDepth - 1].SourcePageType == typeof(Page1))
    Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(Frame.BackStackDepth - 1);
```

The app now works as intended.